# Merge sorting code c++

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

here is my code for the merge sorting algorithm using c++, it actually compiles but it doesn't give the right result, i went through the code several times but the logic seems true for me  ,so if anyone could help me it would be really great:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int left[], int right[], int a[], int L_lengnth, int R_length){
    int l = L_lengnth;
    int r = R_length;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while(i<l && j<r){
        if(left[i]<right[j]){
            a[k]=left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            a[k]=right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<l){
        a[k]=left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
    }
    while(j<r){
         a[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
    }

}
void mergeSort(int A[], int A_lenght){
    int n = A_lenght;
    if(n<2){
        return;
    }
    int mid = n/2;
    int left[mid];
    int right[n-mid];
    for(int i=0; i<mid-1; i++){
        left[i] = A[i];
    }
    for(int i=mid; i<n-1; i++){
        right[i-mid] = A[i];
    }
    mergeSort(left, mid);
    mergeSort(right, n-mid);
    merge(left,right,A,mid,n-mid);
}
int main()
{
    int Array[11]={1,9,5,6,7,4,3,8,99,81,56};

    cout<<"unsorted"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
       cout<<Array[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    mergeSort(Array,11);

    cout<<"sorted"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
       cout<<Array[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[** here is a screenshot of the result after compilation **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONF7d.png)

Comment: `int Array[n];`  -- This is not legal C++ syntax.  Second, why don't you test with a given set of known numbers, 4 or 5 numbers, instead of asking for input?  That way we can see the data you're testing, and second, you won't be inadvertently using different numbers each time.  `int main() { int data[] = {5, 2, 13, 12, 4}; mergeSort(data, 5);}`  Something like that.

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger. That is usually an easier way to diagnose errors than just reading the code.

Comment: Please don't prompt for input.  Hard code the input, and then tell us what output you get, and what you want.  As it stands, this is not a [mcve]

Comment: @JonnyHenly : It is legal C++ syntax - but *only* if `n` is a compile time constant.  In this case it isn't.

Comment: That is obviously not a C++ compiler.  (Most compilers aren't C++ compilers by default - you need to set some options to force them into standard compliance.)  It has an extension to allow non-const array bounds.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array  shows the array bound has to be a `constexpr` (which is the formal term for a compile time constant).  I am sure someone can find the chapter and verse in the actual standard.

Comment: @MartinBonner I just ran `g++ 4.8.4` with `-Wpedantic` and you are correct. `ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'Array' [-Wvla]`

Comment: @walidwake if you're wondering why you're getting nonsense output, it's because your subtracting 1 from `min` and 1 from `n` in your `mergeSort(...){...}` for loops.

Comment: @Jonny Henly thanks for your help it's working now

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this..

```
void mergeSort(int nElems)
{
double *workSpace = new double [nElems];
recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1);
delete [] workSpace;
}
void recMergeSort(double workSpace[], int lowerBounds, int upperBound)
{
if (lowerBound == upperBound)
return; { else


int mid = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
recMergeSort(workSpace, lowerBound, mid);
recMergeSort(workspace, mid+1, upperBound);
merge(workSpace, lowerBound, mid+1, upperBound);
}
}
void merge(double workSpace[],int lowPtr,int hightPtr,int upperBound){
int j = 0;
int lowerBound = lowPtr;
int mid = highPtr-1;
int n = upperBound-lowerBound+1;

while (lowPtr <= mid && highPtr <= upperBound)
if (theArray[lowPtr] < theArray[highPtr])
workSpace[j++] = theArray[lowPtr++];
else
workSpace[j++] = theArray[highPtr++];
while (lowPtr <= mid)
workSpace[j++] = theArray[lowPtr++];
while (highPtr <= upperBound)
workSpace[j++] = theArray[highPtr++];
for (j=0; j<n; j+++)
    theArray[lowerBound+j] = workSpace[j];


}
```